# django admin use changelist_view queryset for geraldo report

Tags: django, django-queryset, changelist

I have the following variable in my admin:

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    qs = QuerySet
    ...
```

and the following def within the admin:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
    cl = ChangeList(request, self.model, list(self.list_display), 
                    self.list_display_links, self.list_filter, 
                    self.date_hierarchy, self.search_fields,  
                    self.list_select_related, 
                    self.list_per_page, 
                    self.list_editable, 
                    self) 
    ModelAdmin.qs = cl.get_query_set()
    return super(ModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

I'm using this to generate reports with geraldo reporting as follows:

```
def groupreport(self, request, extra_context=None):
    resp = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    report = MOdelGroupReport(queryset=ModelAdmin.qs.extra(order_by = ['project_string','code','-pub_date']))
    report.generate_by(PDFGenerator, filename=resp)
    return resp
```

It works well on my development machine however when I deploy it on a UWSGI server the report prints the entire queryset rather than the current filtered queryset. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the actions feature of the admin and used the queryset passed into that.